# Adding AFNetworking causes compile errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

i have followed the steps for adding `AFNetworking` library.
just drag the "AFNetworking" library to the project and selecting copy files option.
when i build the project i get:

[image]

[image]

any ideas in the crowd?
thanks!

Comment: Show the line in the AFNetworking source that is generating the error.

Comment: Seems like the `NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER` macro is borked.  What version of Xcode are you running?

Comment: Try adding Foundation Framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER` was added in Xcode 6.

But you can just use the following snippet in a global header file of your project, if you have to use Xcode 5 or an older SDK.

```
#ifndef NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER
#if __has_attribute(objc_designated_initializer)
#define NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER __attribute((objc_designated_initializer))
#else
#define NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: Yes that would be the best choice, in my opinion!

Comment: The updated framework with the `NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER` definition (similar to the snippet above) was introduced in Xcode 6 to define which initializer is the designated one and which ones are convenience initializers. (See: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014150-CH1-SW8 ) You can just use the snippet above if you need to stay at Xcode 5. But as many bugs were fixed and features added, the update to Xcode 6 is the best choice imho.